# Could it be possible that VOIP pushes get delayed or lost?

Tags: ios, voip, pushkit

I have been working on a VOIP based application. The deployment target is 8.0.
I have used the `PUSHKit` framework for VOIP push notification.  My application runs in the background and rely on VOIP pushes for chat & call notifications.

The server is based on node.js and uses the following for VOIP push.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn-test

Most often when the iOS app is in background, it either receives the VOIP push late or the VOIP push is missed.  At the server end, it is reported that the VOIP APN has been sent successfully.
I am not able to identify where the issue lies. If anyone has faced similar issue or have any idea please help.

NOTE: VoIP pushes are considered high-priority notifications and are delivered without delay.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Its as simple as this:  
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            messages =             {
                msg = "SOCKET_DISCONNECT";
            };
        };
        badge = 0;
        sound = "ping.aiff";
    };
}

Comment: Delay must be on Apples servers or on the connection to the phone (or in the phone)... Have you tried rebooting the phone and making sure it has a strong wifi connection? Perhaps your network provider is causing problems.

Comment: Are you setting the priority? https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn/blob/master/doc/notification.markdown#notificationpriority

Comment: @ajostergaard: This does not occur every time, but its frequent. The network connection seems to be good as most of the time the VOIP notifications after that are received. I am testing with network providers and it happens in that scenario also.  
For the priority of the notification, please let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the priority.

https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn/blob/master/doc/notification.markdown#notificationpriority

Comment: As it a VOIP push notification, the notification priority is set to 10 by default.

Comment: Ok - as far as I can tell you still need to set the priority but perhaps I'm wrong. :)

Comment: @neha_sinha19 -- I too get the same sporadic behavior with VoIP notifications. Were you able to resolve this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use this simplepush.php file

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):


      $deviceToken = '1234567890123456789';
//


// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ProjectName';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PemFileName.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
//  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
                     'content-available'=> 1,
                     'alert' => $message,
                     'sound' => 'default',
                     'badge' => 0,
                     );



// Encode the payload as JSON

$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Use below commands to create pem file and use it in above code

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushCert.pem

# Convert .p12 to .pem. Enter your pass pharse which is the same pwd that you have given while creating the .p12 certificate. PEM pass phrase also same as .p12 cert.  
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey1.pem -in pushkey.p12

Enter Import Password:

MAC verified OK

Enter PEM pass phrase:

Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

# To remove passpharse for the key to access globally. This only solved my stream_socket_client() & certificate capath warnings.
$ openssl rsa -in PushKey1.pem -out PushKey1_Rmv.pem

Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey1.pem:

writing RSA key

# To join the two .pem file into one file:
$ cat PushCert.pem PushKey1_Rmv.pem > ApnsDev.pem
```

After that go to simplepush.php location and fire command -> php simplepush.php

This way you can test your push kit notification setup architecture.

This setup and settings will help you to understand certificates are created and used properly or not. If problem in certificate creating and usage then it will show notification as sent, but you will never receive on device.

In any php or .net or other code will never acknowledge that notification is in queue or it is been cancelled, it will always show you notification is sent.